# Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g^{[n]} (z) ) $ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, dynamical-systems, radicals

Let $^{[*]} $ denote composition.
Let $f(z) = \sqrt z$ and $g(z) = z^2 + 1$
Define $Q(z)$ as

$$ Q(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g^{[n]} (z) ) $$

Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g^{[n]} (z) ) $ analytic for $Re(z) > 11$ ?

Comment: How do you know the limit exists? What branch of $\sqrt{z}$ are you choosing? Also, any reason in particular why you are interested in the case Re$(z) > 11$?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096863/conjecture-about-az-lim-bn-cn-z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $$Q(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g^{[n]} (z)); \;\;\;g(z)=z^2+1; \;\;\;f(z)=\sqrt{z}$$

is analytic and well defined so long as $|g^{[n]}(z)|$ gets arbitrariliy large.  When I have more time, I'll calculate the Laurent series for the limit of the composition and add it to this post. **see below**

Most points grow arbitrarily large where the limit is defined.  But there should be a set of Cantor dust points on the Julia set boundary for which the composition is not defined.  For example, $z=\pm 1/2 \pm i\sqrt{7/4}\;\;z=\pm 1/2 \pm i \sqrt{3/4}$ are eight of the points in the Cantor dust where the limit is not defined, since at these points, iterating g goes to a fixed point or a two-cycle.  I'll provide more details when I have more time.

**continued**
What you are looking for is the Bottcher function for g(z), where we move the fixed point from infinity to zero.  So, instead of iterating $z \mapsto g(z)$, we iterate $z \mapsto \frac{1}{g(1/z)}$

Call this new function $$g2(x)=\frac{1}{x^{-2}+1} = x^2-x^4+x^6-x^8+x^{10}-x^{12}...$$
Then g2 has super-attracting fixed point at x=0, and therefore has a formal Bottcher series, which turn's out to be the Op's desired function, whose formal series solution is posted below where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\;$ since $\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/x}}$

$$B(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g2^{[n]} (x) )$$
Notice that B(x) meets the definition of the Bottcher function, $B(g2(x)) = B(x)^2$, where we are putting iterating g2(x) into correspondence with iterating x^2.  Finally, B(x) leads to a Laurent series for the Op's desired analytic function.

$$Q(x) = \frac{1}{B(1/x)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{[n]} ( g^{[n]} (x) ) $$
As noted, the function is not defined at an uncountable set of points corresponding to a Cantor dust.  See Complex Dynamical Systems edited by Devaney, chapter 1, "The Complex dynamics of quadratic polynomials"

```
{B=
 x
+x^ 3* -1/2
+x^ 5*  1/8
+x^ 7*  5/16
+x^ 9* -101/128
+x^11*  321/256
+x^13* -1515/1024
+x^15*  1677/2048
+x^17*  57235/32768
+x^19* -440827/65536
+x^21*  3216383/262144
+x^23* -6517069/524288
+x^25* -7260785/4194304
+x^27*  292133525/8388608
+x^29* -2439251715/33554432 ...}
```

I noticed the Op also asked if $Q(z)$ defined/analytic $\forall \; \Re(z)>11$?  I think 11 was probably a typo and the Op meant $\forall \; Re(z)>1?$

The answer is yes, since it is not too difficult to show iterating $$g(z)=z^2+1;\; \forall\; \Re(z)\ge 1;\; |g(z)| \ge \sqrt{4+\Im(z)^4} \ge 2$$

And once we have $|g(z)| \ge 2$ we can trivially show iterating $g(z)$ one more time leads to $|g(g(z))|\ge 3$, and further iterations get arbitrarily large where the Botcher function is always defined.  So then all of the points in the Cantor dust have $|\Re(z)|<1\; \text{and}\; |\Im(z)|<2$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for this great answer. Actually, your answer has been baffling me several days until I finally realized that I misread the problem by interchanging the role of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Accepted. But i wonder how it looks like.